# Defining rubber lengths

Tags: spacing

There are many related questions on this topic, but I still do not understand how the mechanism works. In the below code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    paperwidth=30pc,%
    paperheight=48pc,%
    margin=6pc,%
]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\newcommand\divider{%
  \par\bigskip\noindent\hfill\pgfornament[width=10pt]{6}\hfill\null\par\bigskip
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{quoting}

\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
First line.

\begin{quoting}
\lipsum[4]
\end{quoting}

\divider

Last line

\end{document}
```

How should I define the vertical space before the `divider` such that the vertical spacing of `divider` does not add anything extra of the vertical spacing of the `quoting` environment? (Thus, how do I handle the issue in general.)

Comment: I can't say about 'in general', but in this particular case adding `\vskip-\lastskip` at the very beginning of the `\divider` definition helps.

Comment: Use `\addvspace{\bigskipamount}` instead of `\bigskip`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `\addvspace{\bigskipamount}` instead of `\bigskip`. The purpose of `\addvspace` is precisely to add just the largest between two such consecutive specifications; all lists (including `quoting`) add their surrounding vertical spacing with `\addvspace`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
    paperwidth=30pc,%
    paperheight=48pc,%
    margin=6pc,%
]{geometry}
\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
\usepackage{quoting}

\usepackage{pgfornament}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand\divider{%
  \par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}
  \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\pgfornament[width=10pt]{6}}%
  \par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}
}

\newcommand{\baddivider}{%
  \par\bigskip\noindent\hfill\pgfornament[width=10pt]{6}\hfill\null\par\bigskip
}


\begin{document}

First line.

\begin{quoting}
\lipsum[4]
\end{quoting}

\divider

Last line

\clearpage

First line.

\begin{quoting}
\lipsum[4]
\end{quoting}

\baddivider

Last line

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you want to correct spacing after `quoting` environment. A simple, but not general, solution may be as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    paperwidth=30pc,%
    paperheight=48pc,%
    margin=6pc,%
]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\newcommand\divider{%
  \par\bigskip\noindent\hfill\pgfornament[width=10pt]{6}\hfill\null\par\bigskip
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{quoting}

\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
First line.


\begin{quoting}
\lipsum[4]
\end{quoting}\unskip % here -- PS


\divider

Last line

\end{document}
```